# What Parameters does in a for loop function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, parameters

I learn `function` in javascript. I want to print out `"hahahahahahahahahaha!"` and this is a solution that I found but I do not understand what `para` does in a `for loop`? Any explanation appreciated. Thank you.

```
function laugh(para) {
var sum = "";
for (var x = 0; x < para; x++) {
    sum += "ha";
}
return sum += "!";
}
console.log(laugh(10));
```

Comment: Debug with `console.log(para)` and learn about the for loop by reading documentation.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for

Comment: `parameters` are just special `variables` that are set to the `arguments` you pass to the function.

Answer (score 0):

`para` is the parameter (the number 10) you are passing the function when you call it. It determines the number of time the loop runs.

```js
function laugh(para) {
var sum = "";
for (var x = 0; x < para; x++) {
    sum += "ha";
}
return sum += "!";
}

function laugh2(count) {
var sum = "";
for (var x = 0; x < count; x++) {
    sum += "ha";
}
return sum += "!";
}
console.log(laugh(10));
console.log(laugh(40));
console.log(laugh(100));

console.log(laugh2(10));
console.log(laugh2(40));
console.log(laugh2(100));
```

Comment: So it means the number 10 replaced para in a `for loop`?

Comment: Yes and it doesn't have to be para, para is just short for parameter I would guess.

Comment: Understand now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
x < para
```

is the condition to be satisfied for the loop to end.
**para** sets the limit so that as long as **x** is smaller than the loop continues.